# Parachain cannot build blocks after winning a slot

Tags: parachain, block-production, auctions

We have a slight issue: we won a parachain slot on Saturday and are still waiting to produce blocks this Monday.
https://polkadot.subscan.io/block/14512138?tab=event

We should be producing blocks by now since it has been at least an era since we won our slot. Our parathread was not producing blocks with imported #0 whilst we were bidding.

Here are some points to help with some questions:

**Genesis state**

> We have confirmed that the head in the relay chain is the same as the export-genesis-state from the chain spec and that we built our chainspecs using `build-spec`: https://github.com/t3rn/t3rn/blob/master/specs/t3rn.raw.json and here's the clear version: https://github.com/t3rn/t3rn/blob/master/specs/t3rn.json

> head: `0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061f523881c58116b34662cc35d2e921dd63fbd1132f66c3b4c54aba09c0a9e8d03170a2e7597b7b7e3d84c05391d139a62b157e78786d8c082f29dcf4c11131400` which seems to be the same length as others.

**Greyed out in parachain info**

> We noticed we are also greyed out on the parachains tab. Is this relevant?

**Do invulnerable collators need balance?**

> We set our invulnerable collators with zero balance, do they need a balance to author blocks?

**Minimum session candidates**

> We have also set out minimum session candidates to two, which seems sane since we have two collators.

**Block hash at genesis `0`**

> Our block hash for genesis is set to `0x4545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545`, which we **assume** will be enriched after the block is imported.

There doesn't seem to be any logs regarding this at trace level.

**Useful links**

Here's our node endpoint:
https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fws.t3rn.io#/chainstate

And our runtime is open source, here:
https://github.com/t3rn/t3rn/tree/master/runtime/t3rn-parachain/src

Do you have any idea what issue we may be facing? We are currently stumped since it doesn't seem like we are doing anything wrong. This configuration is also roughly the same config as our `t0rn` deployment on rococo.

Comment: Can you include logs from when you start your collator node as well as the flags that you have used to start your node?

Comment: Please start by reviewing this checklist: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1394/our-parachain-doesnt-produce-blocks-checklist/1395#1395

Comment: Make sure you have inserted your keys. Looks like your `aura.authorities` keys are empty in your chain spec.

Comment: Hey Bruno, with regard to authorities, we never set it because we had pallet-session enabled. This could definitely have been our downfall. Lemme get back to you on here with the right info.

Comment: Looks like your chain is now running. Congrats! Please update here with an answer as to what the issue was as this could be beneficial to others 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we found the issue, thanks to the [checklist here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1394/our-parachain-doesnt-produce-blocks-checklist/1395#1395) - Thanks a bunch @bruno.

We had previously checked whether `author.hasKey` worked, and we overlooked it since it didn't return `true` for us on t0rn.

Actually, it turned out to be a slight mismatch. Once we had rubber ducked through the list, we were inserting via RPC but not inserting the key into the node via `key insert`, and we were also calling `author.rotateKeys` in our deployment script, which added to the mix. Once we issued `key insert` we started building blocks.