# Parachain doesn't produce blocks (collation wasn't advertised to any validator)

Tags: parachain, parachain-collator, substrate-parachain-template

I am running a local testnet of a 2-validator-node polkadot Relay Chain (release-v0.9.27) and I am trying to connect a parachain-template to it (v0.9.27), with custom keys. The Relay Chain is working as intended, producing and finalizing blocks.

When I connect the parachain (have tried with 1 collator and 2 collators) to the Relay Chain, the parachain tries to import the first block but never does it, and all I get is `Collation wasn't advertised to any validator`. That procedure continues for a while (5-10mins) and then I get the following errors:

```
[Parachain] Block import error: State Database error: Too many sibling blocks inserted
[Parachain] Error with block built on 0xda79ce961787fcc5e5a97a19cd2a03695b30ee1791fb94a5045cf58f164951d0: Import failed: State Database error: Too many sibling blocks inserted
[Parachain] Failed to collect collation info. error=Application(UnknownBlock("Header was not found in the database: 0x89acf273da66c70e14bd8c5daac0f82235522d15a61ef0a06d925dcf08a3340d"))
```

I have checked everything in these sanity checklists ([How can I get my parachain to produce blocks? (sanity checklist)](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/178/how-can-i-get-my-parachain-to-produce-blocks-sanity-checklist) and [Our parachain doesn't produce blocks [checklist]](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1394/our-parachain-doesnt-produce-blocks-checklist)) and everything should work.

I have also tried increasing the Validator count of the Relay Chain to 3 and I am still getting the same results.

Comment: Can you please give more information on how you run the nodes? Do you use docker? Or anything else? You could try running with `--discover-local`.

Comment: Yes please give us more context on your setup. Is there anything different in your setup than what is in the repo? I can run v0.9.27 relay chain with parachains fine on my machine. Ideally give us something we can reproduce and troubleshoot on our machines to best help you.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/CherryNetwork/polkadot (branch = cherry) and https://github.com/CherryNetwork/evm-parachain/tree/main/runtime (branch = main). I am not using a docker. I just build and run.

The steps I am doing in more details are the following:
1. Spin up the first validator Relay node
2. Spin up the second validator Relay node
3. Insert their keys through a curl command
4. Register the ParaId (2000)
5. Spin the parachain collator node
6. Insert their keys through a curl command
7. Use parasSudoWrapper to Initialize the parachain

Comment: I have also tried running the `v0.9.27` and `v0.9.28` polkadot and rococo Relay. I got the exact same results.

When I run my custom branches with `--alice` and `--bob` everything works btw. It is kinda strange.

Comment: Can you try to replicate the same issue using Zombienet and let me know. Here is a post on spinning up a test network using Zombienet: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/how-do-i-spin-up-a-testnet-with-zombienet

Comment: I tried adding the `--discover-local` tag and it didn't work unfortunately. Thank you @bkchr.
I will try tomorrow the Zombienet and will let you know @Bruno. Thank you as well!

Comment: @Bruno Sorry for my super late reply. Was working on some other stuff. I tried Zombienet but I couldn't really reproduce the issue. I was expecting Zombienet to work because it uses `--alice` and `--bob`. I am still pretty confused of this issue... it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is answered [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5397/how-to-properly-set-session-keys-for-relay-and-parachain-with-custom-keys). Apparently there was a problem inserting the keys. After following all the steps of the solution, my parachain could produce and finalize blocks.